# Cython Build Service

Tags: python, cython

I'm working on porting a Python package over to Cython, but would rather provide as many pre-compiled binary packages of it as possible so that users don't need to have Cython on their system.

I've had no lucking finding one so it probably doesn't exist but is there a Cython package build service available somewhere? Basically, I want to be able to build for Windows, Linux, Mac, ARM in both x86 and x64 varieties which means I need to create at least 8 separate builds. I'd certainly be willing to either pay for or go through the hassle of setting up an automated build system that would do that for me, on demand.

Also, I don't currently own a Mac and would rather not have to buy one just for the sake of building this package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question is specific to Cython, but rather any Python module which has `Extension`s.

Several of the Continuous Integration services allow you to create build "artifacts". You can use this feature to automate your builds.

I've used Appveyor to do this for Windows (https://www.appveyor.com/) - see an example project here: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/snorfalorpagus/appveyordemo

I'm aware that Travis can do this for Linux and OS X, although I've not tried this myself.

I've found that using Anaconda greatly simplifies things (http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html).

I'm not aware of a single system that does everything but that may just be because I've never looked.